# Startx with multiple command without a file

Tags: bash, shell, startx

I'm trying to run a graphic application from command line (i.e chromium) with some extra programs (i.e. cec-control, resolution settings etc).

So far I'm able to do that running `startx` with the file name of a script:

script.sh

```
xrandr -r 1280x720
cec-script
/use/non/chromium-browser ...
```

With this file I just have to do:

`startx script.sh`

What I really would like to do is to be able to run those commands from a python script that allows to choose between different configuration without the need of extra scripts (at this point I have too many scripts for too many configurations), what I tried so far doesn't seems to work:

`startx eval $'xrandr -r 1280x720; cec-script; /use/bin/chromium-browser ...' --`

And many others variants that used `stdin` as file, the problem is that everything I try fails, I only get the message that X terminated successfully and nothing more.

do you have any suggestion on how to give `startx` multiple command from the command line?

Comment: How exactly do you want to run `startx` with your commands? Manually from a terminal? From a script? Please [edit] your question to clarify this. You could use a wrapper script that creates a script for `startx` on the fly, runs `startx` specifying this temporary script and removes the script afterwards.

Comment: Edited, I'm running startx from a python script that allows to choose between different configurations, I already thought about that option but it seems ridiculous to me that it cannot be done without such a dirty trick

Comment: The interface of `startx` is defined this way. (Read `man startx`.) It accepts an argument to specify **the first client** program to start. This is normally a program that will (or allows to) start other clients. So your python can do what I already suggested. Using a script is not a "dirty trick", it is the most common thing on a UNIX system.